# How to implement the "latch" function used by the search function in this T-link-tree paper?

Tags: c, algorithm, concurrency, tree, locking

From this paper, *[Tlink-tree: Main memory index structure with concurrency control and recovery](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/262402220_Tlink-tree_Main_memory_index_structure_with_concurrency_control_and_recovery) by Jan Lindström*, we have the following algorithm shown:

```
Search(key, P) {
  P = root page; 
  slatch(P);
  do {
    h = high-key(P);
    l = low-key(P);
    if (key < l) {
      Q = P.left;
      slatch(Q);
      unlatch(P);
      P = Q;
    } else if (key > h) {
      if (P is a leaf page) {
        Q = P.successor;
      } else {
        Q = P.right;
      }
      slatch(Q);
      unlatch(P);
      P = Q;
    } else {
      search key from P;
      if (bounding key value found) {
        slatch(P.ptr); 
        R = P.ptr; 
        unlatch(P);
        search key from R;
      }
      return R or NULL if not found;
    }
  } while (P);
}
```

In addition, we have these notes:

- `slatch(P)`: Fix page P and acquire a shared latch on P.
- `xlatch(P)`: Fix page P and acquire an exclusive latch on P.
- `unlatch(P)`: Release the latch on page P and unfix P.
- `slock(r)`: Acquire an unconditional shared lock on record r.
- `xlock(r)`: Acquire an unconditional exclusive lock on record r.
- `unlock(r)`: Release the lock on record r.

I am wondering how to represent this in JavaScript so I can better understand how this works in practice. Not quite there yet, need to figure out the data structure (JSON representation) and the rest of the details of this `search` function:

```
function search(tree, key) {
  let node = tree
  slatch(node)
  do {
    let h = node.highKey
    let l = node.lowKey
    if (key < l) {
      let newNode = node.left
      slatch(newNode)
      unlatch(node)
      node = newNode
    } else if (key > h) {
      let newNode
      if (node is a leaf page) {
        newNode = node.successor
      } else {
        newNode = node.right
      }
      slatch(newNode)
      unlatch(node)
      node = newNode
    } else {
      search key from node
      if (bounding key value found) {
        slatch(node.ptr) 
        R = node.ptr 
        unlatch(node)
        search key from R
      }
      return R or NULL if not found
    }
  } while (node)
}
```

My question in this post is, I don't understand what the `slatch` and related functions (and `P`) are doing or what they would do if you were to implement this in C (at a deep technical level). What do they mean? What would they be doing exactly in C, for example? Or if you were to implement this in JavaScript using webworkers, would you need this functionality too? What would it look like then? What would be the implementation of this method?

In the paper they state:

> A latch is implemented by a
> low-level primitive (semaphore) that provides a cheap synchronization mechanism but no deadlock detection. Lock
> request may be made with the conditional or the unconditional option. A conditional request means that the requester (transaction) is not willing to wait if the lock cannot
> be granted immediately. An unconditional request means
> that the requester is willing to wait until the lock is granted.
> We use physiological logging [18] as a compromise between physical logging and logical logging. We assume
> that the buffer manager employs the steal and no-force
> buffering policies [18].

I am reading [this](https://www.csd.uoc.gr/%7Ehy460/pdf/p650-lehman.pdf) for more background on t-trees.

Comment: Why do this in JS? It's single-threaded and event-driven and so doesn't offer support for these sort of lock mechanisms. I think you'll have way more fun if you use a system language that offers direct access to threading and synchronization.

Comment: Okay let's do this in bare C then, or assembly, on mac or linux.